# Is it the custom to thank someone for editing my question?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few times someone has edited an answer of mine; fixed some spelling errors or the like.  Is it the custom to thank such editors in a comment or somewhere?  I'm not sure if there is even a way, as the comment autofill seems only to work for people who've commented on the answer.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope. Such a comment (if it was merely "thanks for the edit" or something similar) would likely be deleted as noise.

You're actually able to ping users who have edited your posts - they'll receive the notification even though it won't autocomplete, so make sure you get the spelling correct - but there's not really any need. If you feel like their edit was confusing or they misconstrued your point, you might ping them to let them know that but, in general, there's no need to thank people for anything here in comments.

Some of our users do hang out in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence) and if they're one of them, you're more than welcome to thank them there.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Catija's good answer, I'd say, the custom is to pass it on.. That is, edit to improve others' posts if you see an opportunity. :)